# CSS Floated divs are overlapping on window resize. How do I stop this?

Tags: css, html, nested, overlap

I have just re-done my website at www.chartoonz.com

I have created a wrapper div in which I have placed a div with a links to my videos on vimeo.  I float this div left, next to it I have floated a div with some text about the movie and floated it right.  The columns look ok, until the window resizes.  Then they overlap terrribly and I cannot figure out why.  In the event of a narrow window resize, I want the right float column to jump underneath the left floated column.

**The relevant HTML looks like this:**

```
<div id="CopyWrapper" >

        <div class = "copyFloatLeft">
        <p><strong>Use Video to Communicate.</strong></p>
        <p><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/90334225" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
        <br />
        </p>
        <br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class = "copyFloatRight">
            <strong>Corporate Communications</strong> 
            <p> Corporate communications can be greatly enhanced through a well presented video. Ideas and concepts are easier to understand when they can be seen clearly and their meaning is made plain. Here, I present some of the work I did over the last few months, helping the Merrill Lynch digital advertising division get their message out.</p>
    </div>

    <br /> 
</div>
<br class="clearFloat" />
```

**The governing CSS looks like this:**

```
#CopyWrapper{
background: center;
text-align: left;
display: block;
float: left;
width: 65%;
padding-left: 200px;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
clear: both;
overflow: hidden;
}


.copyFloatLeft{
background: center;
width: 45%;
margin:5px;
padding: 15px 15px 5px 15px;
position: relative;
clear: right;
float: left;
display: block;
}



.copyFloatRight{
background: center;
width: 45%;
margin:5px;
padding: 15px 15px 5px 15px;
position: relative;
clear: right;
float: right;
display: block;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Aharon

Answer (score 0):

`.copyFloatLeft` and `.copyFloatRight` blocks should **both float to the left**

and for the iframes I would do something like:

```
#CopyWrapper iframe {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.  It hadn't occured to me that I needed to treat the iframe!